# AWS error while parsing .config YAML file in .ebextension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

When deploying to Elasticbeanstalk, my deploy fails with a parsing error caused by a .config file i have in the .ebextension folder, but it seems ok to me. Anyone can tell me how to fix it?
The .config file looks like this:

```
files:
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_copy_htaccess_after_deployment.sh":
     mode: "000755",
     owner: root,
     group: root,
     content: |
       yes | /bin/cp /var/app/current/.htaccess.new /var/app/current/.htaccess
```

And the error:

> The configuration file
>   .ebextensions/08_htaccess_create_script_post_deploy.config in
>   application version
>   git-bce52a5381c7ac6735249419c48b1fe116168610-1494415808045 contains
>   invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while parsing a
>   block mapping in "", line 3, column 10: mode: "000755", ^
>   expected , but found FlowEntry in "", line 3,
>   column 24: mode: "000755", ^ , JSON exception: Invalid JSON:
>   Unexpected character (f) at position 0.. Update the configuration
>   file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the aws dcumentation you dont need to use comas behind mode owner and group. so your yml config file should look like this:

```
files:
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_copy_htaccess_after_deployment.sh":
     mode: "000755"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       yes | /bin/cp /var/app/current/.htaccess.new /var/app/current/.htaccess
```

and here is an example of the syntax

```
files:  
  "target file location on disk": 
     mode: "six-digit octal value"
     owner: name of owning user for file
     group: name of owning group for file
     source: URL
     authentication: authentication name:

  "target file location on disk": 
     mode: "six-digit octal value"
     owner: name of owning user for file
     group: name of owning group for file
     content: |
    this is my content
     encoding: encoding format
     authentication: authentication name:
```